# Is it possible to use multiprocessing in a module with windows?

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I'm currently going through some pre-existing code with the goal of speeding it up. There's a few places that are extremely good candidates for parallelization. Since Python has the GIL, I thought I'd use the multiprocess module.

However from my understanding the only way this will work on windows is if I call the function that needs multiple processes from the highest-level script with the `if __name__=='__main__'`  safeguard. However, this particular program was meant to be distributed and imported as a module, so it'd be kind of clunky to have the user copy and paste that safeguard and is something I'd really like to avoid doing.

Am I out of luck or misunderstanding something as far as multiprocessing goes? Or is there any other way to do it with Windows?

Comment: What would lead you to think that?

Comment: @Natecat MP on windows doesn't have fork so without the `if \_\_name\_\_` it will act like a subprocess bomb.

Comment: Tyler, thought a bit about it and only way I could see this working is if you treat MP logic like it behaves on Windows (socket based server) and have a  server object called in the user program's if __name__.   Keep in mind it would have to be very big or complicated.   if __main__ would instantiate as `myLib.As_master()` or `myLib.As_client()` and then check in your library for `Is_master()` all of these would be static methods that set a static module variable to something like True or False.   Don't have it import anything in your library but have everything import it.  1/2

Comment: 2/2 Just don't turn it into a god module.   Also keep in mind you would only need to import it for modules that use MProcessing.

Comment: Doesn't Python have threading?  On Windows, that would be the proper solution.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Python does but it has something called a global interpreter lock so that only one thread is executing at a time.  The GIL has been a big source of annoyance that a sizable population have been trying to murder for a while now - https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: @David: thanks.  Just because I can never resist sticking my oar in, is there no way to get the `multiprocessing` module to load just Tyler's module into the new process, rather than the highest-level script?  Or could it be modified to support doing so?

Comment: @HarryJohnston With MP for windows, lack of `fork()` is a pain.  MP Windows spawns a child process with the argument for the handle/id of pipe to serialize communication and then reloads the program which will run until it hits the same Process call and bomb out.  Some flavors of Windows you can hang the computer with that.  I think my answer below might work though.

Comment: @David, 3.4+ also supports `'spawn'` and `'forkserver'` start methods on Unix systems. The fork server approach is a good choice for multithreaded applications, so the problem isn't limited to Windows.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, see [`multiprocessing.spawn.get_preparation_data`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.6.0a1/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#l140). It's hard coded to use `sys.modules['__main__']`.

Comment: @eryksun: I imagine that could be fixed, though.  At least in principle.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, ISTM that the spawn vs fork interpreter states should be similar, and a forked process inherits the process state of having executed the main script.

Comment: @eryksun: I'm not saying it should do that by default, but if there was an option for it it would (presumably) solve Tyler's problem.  I would imagine that such an option would only be made available if you were using the `spawn` method.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, it could be a good idea to implement for the `'spawn'` (and maybe `'forkserver'` ) start methods, but it would need to be discussed on python-ideas, and I can almost guarantee that it would only make it into 3.7+.

Answer (score 3):

For everyone still searching:

#### inside module

```
from multiprocessing import Process
    
def printing(a):
    print(a)

def foo(name):
    var={"process":{}}
    if name == "__main__":
        for i in range(10):
            var["process"][i] = Process(target=printing , args=(str(i)))
            var["process"][i].start()

        for i in range(10):
            var["process"][i].join
```

#### inside main.py

```
import data

name = __name__

data.foo(name)
```

#### output:

```
>>2
>>6
>>0
>>4
>>8
>>3
>>1
>>9
>>5
>>7
```

I am a complete noob so please don't judge the coding OR presentation but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

On ms-windows, you should be able to import the *main module* of a program without side effects like starting a process.

When Python imports a module, it actually runs it.

So one way of doing that is in the `if __name__ is '__main__'` block.

Another way is to do it from within a function.

The following won't work on ms-windows:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo():
    print('hello')

p = Process(target=foo)
p.start()
```

This is because it tries to start a process when importing the module.

The following example from the programming guidelines is OK:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support, set_start_method

def foo():
    print('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    set_start_method('spawn')
    p = Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
```

Because the code in the if block doesn't run when the module is imported.

But putting it in a function should also work:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo():
    print('hello')

def bar()
    p = Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
```

When this module is run, it will *define* two new functions, not run then.

Comment: Whoever's writing the program that uses this module still needs to write their own `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard. The question is asking if there's a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in comments, perhaps you could do something like

```
#client_main.py
from mylib.mpSentinel import MPSentinel

#client logic

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MPSentinel.As_master()

#mpsentinel.py

class MPSentinel(object):

    _is_master = False

@classmethod
def As_master(cls):
    cls._is_master = True

@classmethod
def Is_master(cls):
    return cls._is_master
```

It's not ideal in that it's effectively a singleton/global but it would work around window's lack of fork.   Still you could use MPSentinel.Is_master() to use multiprocessing optionally and it should prevent Windows from process bombing.

Answer (score 0):

i've been developing an instagram images scraper so in order to get the download & save operations run faster i've implemented multiprocesing in one auxiliary module, note that this code it's inside an auxiliary module and not inside the main module.

The solution I found is adding this line:

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
```

pretty simple but it's actually working!

```
def multi_proces(urls, profile):
    img_saved = 0
    if __name__ != '__main__':          # line needed for the sake of getting this NOT to crash
        processes = []
        for url in urls:
            try:
                process = multiprocessing.Process(target=download_save, args=[url, profile, img_saved])
                processes.append(process)
                img_saved += 1
            except:
                continue

        for proce in processes:
            proce.start()

        for proce in processes:
            proce.join()
    return img_saved

def download_save(url, profile,img_saved):
        file = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)  # Download
        open(f"scraped_data\{profile}\{profile}-{img_saved}.jpg", 'wb').write(file.content)  # Save
```